# How to pass Raw query result from controller to view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-views

I need to generate a number from database and show it on input at view.

I use function on MySQL to achieve that so I use raw expression.

```
    $nomor = DB::table('customers')- 
    >selectRaw('concat(year(now()),lpad(month(now()),2,0),lpad(id, 3, 0))  
    as nomor')
    ->where('id', '=', $customers->id)->get();
```

When I pass the variable into view,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control  @error('nomor') is-invalid @enderror" id="nomor" placeholder="" name="nomor" value="{{ $nomor }}">
```

current result:
[image: current result]

> "[{"nomor":"201909001"}]"

my expected result is:

> 201909001 *withoutquote*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `get()` function, the function returns an array with all results of your query.

As example, if your select returns 3 lines, the `$nomor` returns a collection (like an array with steroids) with 3 positions, one per line returned by the query and, in each position, the `get()` function returns an object with the properties as your select, so, in this case, the correct way to access the `nomor` column is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control  @error('nomor') is-invalid @enderror" id="nomor" placeholder="" name="nomor" value="{{ $nomor[0]->nomor }}">
```

Note, instead calling only `$nomor` object, we access the first line of the result `$nomor[0]` and get the property that corresponds to the column name of the query `$nomor[0]->nomor`

Comment: I've tried $nomor ->nomor and $nomor[0]['nomor'] . thank you william for the answers. I ll try it once i got home.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `->get()`, you get a `Collection`, which is essentially an array with additional functionality. When you use `{{ $nomor }}`, you're outputting the whole contents of the `Collection`. To fix this, use `->first()`:

```
$nomor = DB::table('customers')
->selectRaw('concat(year(now()),lpad(month(now()),2,0),lpad(id, 3, 0)) as nomor')
->where('id', '=', $customers->id)
->first();
```

Then in your view, access it as an `object` (since `DB::table()->first()` will return a `stdClass`):

```
<input type="text" ... value="{{ $nomor->nomor }}"/>
```